# Let's clean-up those rock identification questions

Tags: discussion

We now have more than 200 [rock-identification](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rock-identification) questions.  Here on meta, we have a [very good guide](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/125/6) on what it takes to write a good rock ID question.  It doesn't take a geologist to recognise that many rock ID question are very far from meeting those guidelines.  Those questions need to be either improved or closed.

I propose that the community undertakes an effort to make sure that we don't have any old and open rock ID questions that fall far short from meeting the guidelines.  As a diamond pro-tem mod, I could close some of them myself, but to grow as a site we need a vigilant community of high-rep users to take care of this, in particular because ultimately it takes domain experts to really determine the quality of questions and answers, in particular on a site covering an interdisciplinary field like ours.

Comment: So we should flag rock identification questions that we believe should be deleted?

Comment: @CamiloRada Yes, please do.

Comment: OK, I've raised a bunch of flags for you guys. I looked for unanswered questions, with deficient information and apparently abandoned by the OP after posting. Let't me know if you feel the criteria was OK.

Comment: Some of my flags were: "declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention". Please let me know if I have abused or misused the flags. And if I have: Why?

Comment: @CamiloRada Apologies, we did not communicate well enough between the moderators.

Comment: No problem. Good to know that was all.