# Are we being too quick to close rock-identification questions?

Tags: discussion

In other Meta questions we [agreed](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1664/idea-make-identification-request-posts-off-topic) to keep rock-identification questions on the site, but to [close them](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1672/39) if they did not have most of all of the information detailed [here](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/125/39). We created a custom close reason for this, and  also [added a warning to the tag wiki](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1718/39).

Since then we have [agreed](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1680/should-we-tolerate-rock-identification-request-questions-if-they-are-answerable) (admittedly with low voting numbers) that if a rock-id question is answerable then it is OK, even if it doesn't have every piece of the required info.

[This question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/17325/help-to-identify-unusual-rock-please), from a first-time user of the site, has practically all of the required information, yet at the time of writing it has three close-votes that all say "you didn't give us the required information". And it's been down-voted.

I don't think the rock-identification question is solved - IMHO it's still dominating the site in an unhealthy way - but while we have a documented process to follow, can we at least not close questions that follow it?!

Comment: That question has been edited. When I voted to close it it had only as text: "Can someone please help to identify this rock? We are hoping it's a meteorite!" I guess the downvote came also before he edited the info

Comment: as i see it the lack of information does not make the question bad so there is no need to down vote it,voting to close the question as a result of too little information is a better way to deal with it as questions can always be reopened when new information emerges.

Comment: @Universal_learner ah, that explains things - and explains why it has remained at only the three (actually now two) close votes. So I guess that's "working as intended" then :-)