# Should rock identification questions be 'one sample per question'?

Tags: discussion

In [this question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/10182/need-help-identifying) the OP asks identification for 4 samples.
(Update: question has been removed by the OP. It contained 4 pictures and basically only asked 'Can anyone identify these?')

Should this be split into 4 questions?

Personally, I'm in favor. It would require more effort from the OP, maybe resulting in better questions.

The famous [A guide for asking “Identify this rock” questions?](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124/a-guide-for-asking-identify-this-rock-questions?rq=1) does not answer this.
If the consensus here is 'yes', a remark should be added there.

Answer (score 3):

**One question, one answer.**

If they are all samples of what the OP believes to be *the same rock*: then they can be together, because the answer will be all the same.

If they are all samples of *different* rocks, they should be asked as individual questions.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019-07-30, [rock identification questions are off-topic on Earth Science Stack Exchange](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1768/6).

Therefore, the question about one or more samples per question no longer applies.