# Removing the "guide for asking rock identification questions" warning from the question review

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, user-interface

If one asks a question with the [identification-request](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) tag, he will see this warning during the review step:

[image]

However, rock identification questions are now [off topic](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1768/18081) on Earth Science SE. I thus suggest that we remove the warning associated with the tag, or better that we replace it by another warning saying that rock identification questions are off topic.

The tag is still being used by (on topic) fossil identification requests, so the warning could be replaced by something like:

> Rock identification questions are off topic.
> If you are looking for help identifying a fossil, please include...

And a small guide, maybe with a link to a more complete guide, as was the case for rocks before. There is a nice one provided by user John [here](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1760/18081).

Comment: I agree with everything you are proposing regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

Right.

These can only be edited by staff (see [Meta Stack Exchange for details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/172266)), so once we reach community consensus on the new text, we will ask a community moderator to edit the text accordingly.