# What straddles the line of 'Identification Request?'

Tags: support, scope

I found out that [identification requests](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1768/28780) are off-topic. I assume this includes questions such as *'What rock is this?' [Image of rock]*, but would questions about identifying certain types of rock (e.g., *'How could I differentiate slate and shale?'*), as opposed to specific rock specimens, be acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

The ban is about `id-my-rock-or-mineral` questions.

We cannot identify from a picture.

Every question related to geological material that is not an `identify-this-stone` question is well received as a petrology, mineralogy or paleontology question.