# How to convincingly ask a serial upvoter to stop doing it when they already know better?

Tags: discussion, voting, votes

In another site, my question about upvoting [Are other people also seeing an increase in upvoting recently?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1009/12102) received this [answer](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1067/12102):

> It was me I've been going around and up voting everybody like crazy and I can't stop myself. I'm so addicted to up voting and I think I need to get help before my up voting gets me into trouble.

I've just experienced an "upvote storm" five minutes ago here in Earth Science SE, coinciding with the same user having been active five minutes ago as well. I'd like to *convincingly inform* the user that this practice is unacceptable in all sites and more than bothersome to the one on the receiving end of the storm. How best to do this decisively?

[image]

Votes removed 10-Dec-2018:

[image]

Comment: It's not cereal. I do others the same way and there's no pattern to it. I think you're allowed to upvote like 100 times a day or something like that. I can't quite randomize for you. Compared  to the way other people down vote I don't think it's a problem.

Comment: I never said it was me seriously

Comment: A while ago I've seen on a meta somewhere a similar thing. The answer from one of the SE people was to just let it go. If it's really extreme an algorithm will pick it up and reverse the votes. Otherwise, enjoy the rep.

Comment: @Gimelist I don't "enjoy" rep but I understand it's utility for some people. I think the site should display only $\log_{10}(rep)$ like dB or pH if at all. But in this case voting without looking (how can one read 10 unrelated posts in two minutes?) is defeating the purpose of rep. It could also be perceived negatively by third parties. SE already has some rules that make things difficult that exist as a result of multi-party rep gamesmanship: [Will/would it be impossible for me to add a third bounty here? Why was 500 my only choice for #2?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/888/12102)

Comment: @Gimelist and especially the answer to [Any way to award a second +100 bounty to a second answer to the same question?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863/12102) You are welcome to not take the site's functions too seriously, but I don' think that that is good advice to be giving to others.

Comment: @uhoh I would like to know for sure?

Comment: @uhoh I also had some up votes removed?  Let me know if you can see it throught this link? https://space.stackexchange.com/users/18879/muze?tab=reputation

Comment: Oh I can see it, thanks, yes so there are other "enthusiastic voters" out there as well. Okay maybe clean up your last two comments (I deleted mine, will delete this one soon.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry too much about it.

The system has algorithms in place to take care of it.

If you suspect someone is out to get you, flag a post for moderator attention and explain the situation.

Comment: I don't think your answer follows from my question. But this is meta, so okay ;-)

Comment: Your question reeks of [interpersonal.SE] ;-)

Comment: I can't even spell intprers... IS SE

Answer (score 1):

I received myself also about 100 points in a minute and I don't carry a lot about points. After returning just 20 points (after reading), my answer on "what is the deepest we have ever traveled to Earth's Center", my best ever, was unmarcked as the most accurated. But well the guy has not a good job and makes interesting questions from time to time, but @Muze anyhow you told me after the graphs my job was nice so I didn't understand it very well. For my cv it is better the green color on my best answer than points (at human resources they read)