# Should we include a suggestion for a displacement test in the rock identification guide?

Tags: discussion, rock-identification-guide

#### Part 1: We want them to do science, right?

People asking [rock-identification](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rock-identification) questions occasionally say things like "it feels heavy for its size", and when that happens I usually think "shouldn't we make them measure that?"

A scale is good enough to measure weight; measuring the volume of an irregularly-shaped object would require a displacement test.

This takes some equipment and a little finesse. And a willingness to let a precious rock get wet. (Of course, one part of the guide recommends that askers *break* their rocks, *quelle barbare!*). Is it worth the effort? Is it worth putting in the rock identification guide?

#### Part 2: technique

Your typical rock-identification poster isn't likely to have a graduated cylinder lying around, but might have a graduated measuring pitcher in their kitchen.

[image: the aforementioned measuring pitcher]

You could just put a small rock in a partially-filled pitcher and read the change in volume directly. I can't speak to whether it would be precise enough.

[image]

(My bathroom scale, which only measures to tenths of kilograms, weighed the sample rock in at about 600 g, for a rough specific gravity of 3).

With a large rock and a bucket with a pouring spout, you could fill the bucket until water is just coming out of the spout, then gently place the rock in the bucket, collecting the overflow in a smaller container.  If the aforementioned measuring pitcher isn't accurate enough to directly read the volume, you could weigh the overflow.

Comment: Good idea. I doubt many will use it, because we already have a guide and 90% of the questions are still "here's a shitty picture, my dad gave it to me 20 years ago, what is this". But I like the initiative

Comment: Yes, we should. Feel free to edit it into the [relevant guide](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/125/6).

Comment: I noticed this is not in there yet

Comment: I added it to the guide.