# Should we extend the Rock ID guide with photo's of the surroundings?

Tags: discussion

In section 3 of [A guide for asking "Identify this rock" questions?](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124/a-guide-for-asking-identify-this-rock-questions?noredirect=1&lq=1), *Describe where you found it*, would it be wise to add the sentence?:

> Add a picture of the surroundings if you have one.

Comment: Also as noticed in an answer a fresh-cut picture is extremely needed when we talk about rocks and the piece can be broken. And also to use a magnifying glass to make a secondary picture should be on the guide in my opinion if it is a rock composed by minerals

Comment: I agree, and also with @Universal_learner suggestions.

Comment: Any additional information is helpful but I believe a lot of requests for ID are being put on hold primarily because the user didn't follow the rules for submission.  In particular questions about the luster, and the hardness of a rock can be difficult for a number of people whose real exposure to the earth sciences are rocks they collect.  If we add one more criteria to the acceptable question format we will be putting even more questions on hold.  I would like to see it added to the guidelines but not used to put a question on hold.

Comment: The question https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/16656/identification-of-a-rock-from-kentucky/16657#16657 is an example of a question that doesn't follow the guidelines and was put on hold.  I worry that we add one more criteria to the checklist and more questions like this example get, in my opinion needlessly, put on hold.

Comment: Yes, so long as it includes the "if you have one" part.