# Do we still need advice how to best describe our rocks?

Tags: discussion, scope

When I forgot to add a title to a question before posting and clicked "review" I got an error  which is good. But since I included the [identification-request](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) tag the advice includes instructions how to better describe my rock.

> Other suggestions
>
> If you are looking for help identifying a rock, please include:
>
> - A well-lit, sharp photo with a scale.
> - A good description of the color, lustre, texture, strength and weight.
> - A location of where the rock was found.
> - And the hardness rating of your rock.
>
> To learn more please visit our [Guide for asking rock identification questions](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124/a-guide-for-asking-identify-this-rock-questions).

If I remember correctly this was an interim effort to improve rock-ID questions before they were finally decided to be off-topic. Do these warnings warrant some updates and/or adjustments?

[image: screen shot of error message]

Comment: You are correct, the tag guidance/description does need changing. I'm guessing it hasn't changed because of oversight. This also begs the question, what do we change it to, something very general? To help in this process, what was the question were you used the tag & why did you use it?

Comment: @Fred it's the tag that triggers the message, so all remaining questions with that tag should be considered, mine just happens to be the most recent. I wonder if the utility and scope of the tag needs to be examined as well?