# Proposal in Area51 to open a new site for identify my rock/mineral/fossil questions

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

## EDIT

## It is not possible.

`We do not accept proposals for identify-this style sites. – animuson♦`

---

Ok, so I went to Area51 and [I posted a proposal to open a new site](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/125662/identify-my-rock-mineral-fossil).

If we remember it, we received ~5 questions each day wich is more than Earth Science ratio (2.6 questions/day). This is enought traffic for a new site.

I think we could manage it better on a separate site with [the guideliness we posted with effort](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/125/20559).

---

## Reasons to open a new site

There are a lot of users on the net searching to identify the minerals or rocks they find. The site would have yes or yes traffic. We received ~5 questions each day.

---

## Reasons not to open a new site

The posters use not to post info and a bad picture. We tried to help them ask better with [this post](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/125662/identify-my-rock-mineral-fossil), leaving an [example about how to ask](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32519/identify-my-rock-or-mineral).

It is sometimes difficult to identify the pieces and geologists may don't want to participate.

---

#### If you want a new site and you are going to participate, please go to Area51 and suport the proposal by upvoting and manifesting your intention to participate.

**## Proposal (needs upvotes)**

**## Discusion (feel free to participate)**

Comment: I'm supporting that for the sole reason of putting an end to this discussion here, and making it someone else's problem

Comment: @gerrit you might want to include `status-declined` tag

Comment: See, even SE itself frowns upon "identify this" websites.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350157/are-there-any-banned-subjects-on-area-51)