# Should this question be re-opened, or should we close this very similar question?

Tags: discussion

I have identified an inconsistency that cannot be good for the site.

This question, [What is this rock?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2152/what-is-this-rock) , has been left open, while this question, [What type of rock is this?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/262/what-type-of-rock-is-this),  has been closed.

Could someone please rectify this by closing them both or re-opening the closed question, or justify why one is on topic and the other is not.

Comment: See also: http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/124/6

Comment: @gerrit, I've seen that thread but it fails to explain the inconsistency I have identified.

Comment: Indeed, I recognise the inconsistency...

Answer (score 2):

Your question was unfortunately closed before a [consensus](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/are-questions-such-as-can-you-identify-this-rock-on-topic) arised on whether or not those [identification-request](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) questions were welcome here and probably nobody thought of reopening it once the consensus was reached.
I, for one, indeed don't see any reason to leave it closed so i voted to reopen.

As a side note, as noted in the comments to your question, indicating where you did found the rock would be a nice addition to the question. Additional informations such as the ones highlighted in [Chris Mueller's "how-to-ask" guide](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124/a-guide-for-asking-identify-this-rock-questions) are also welcome.