# Rock-identification tag: Notification warning

Tags: discussion, feature-request, rock-identification-guide

Creating a [tag notification warning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips) for the [identification-request](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) tag [was suggested](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1713/11908) as a measure to reduce the number of bad quality "identify my rock" questions. I think that is indeed a good idea, but as a community we have to come up with a text for this warning message. This is what I suggest:

> Looks like you are asking for help to identify a rock, and you are in
> the right place.
>
> In your question you are required to include:
>
> - A well-lit, sharp photo with a scale.
> - A good description of the color, lustre, texture, strength and weight.
> - A location of where the rock was found.
> - And the hardness rating of your rock.
>
> To learn more please visit our [Guide for asking rock identification questions](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124/a-guide-for-asking-identify-this-rock-questions).
>
> Note that if you fail to provide the information detailed above, the question will be closed, and if you fix it later it won't get as much attention as a new question, so make it right from the start!

Feel free to edit this questions to make the corrections you fell are necessary to the text, leave your comments about it below or suggest a different text.

Comment: Sounds good to me

Comment: That's seems pretty good for the [tag wiki](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info). But it's a little long for a warning. I think the first and third paragraphs are a pretty good place to start on the warning copy.

Comment: @JonEricson I've edited it to make it shorter. That's better? Still too long?

Comment: The point is we need a warning. I agree just linking to the guide but to include something like "you won't receive an answer if you do not follow this guide"

Answer (score 5):

I've updated the [tag wiki](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info). Feel free to [suggest further edits](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/290).

I also added a warning to the [identification-request](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) tag:

[image: Rock ID warning]

Remember that people universally [don't read](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/04/26/designing-for-people-who-have-better-things-to-do-with-their-lives/), so adding too much text will just cause the warning to be ignored.

Comment: Thank you very much. We needed it long time ago. Anyhow after you did it two new questions with no info appeared so the trouble may not be solved

Comment: It works quite nicely! It popped up when asking [a non-rock `identification-request` question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/16726/6031) but since I do at least read a little, I could quickly determine it wasn't for me. I wonder if you can also make it bright red, blinking, hover slightly above the page, reach out and grab the author's arm and shake it firmly, accompanied by a clap of thunder as well?

Comment: "strength"? Is that supposed to be hardness?

Comment: @person27: Probably? I used the copy from the question, but hardness does sound more likely.

Comment: It looks like the warning is no longer formatted properly -- it just displays raw HTML. Not sure how this works in the site, so should I post a bug report?

Comment: @hichris123: I can't reproduce today. Maybe a temporary bug?