# Standard comment text when VTC ID questions as 'unclear'

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

As suggested in my comment under [Spencer's answer](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1668/595) in the [Idea - make identification request posts off topic](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1664/idea-make-identification-request-posts-off-topic) topic, what could be a 'default' comment text that we can quickly cut and paste a question comment?

Its intention should be to invite people to improve their question so that:

- It becomes a good ID question that is worth staying in the repository that this site is
- New users feel being welcomed

We do not have to address new users specifically, but bad ID questions are often by new users.

To start off, here's a suggestion:

> Your question is getting close votes because it has insufficient information. Please read our [guide for asking “Identify this rock” questions](http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/124/a-guide-for-asking-identify-this-rock-questions) and [edit] your question. If your question is put on hold but you improve it, the community can vote to reopen it.

Comment: What do we do when the OP edits the question, but the edit isn't actually useful? Let's say they posted only pics, and now edit it saying "it feels heavy"?

Comment: @Leave closed (or VTC). If we feel helpful, leave another comment about what's missinsing.