# Shark tooth ID question on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

The question [Identify this...item found on Myrtle Beach](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/17829/identify-this-item-found-on-myrtle-beach) essentially asks "Did I find a shark tooth?"

The title could be better, the question could do with more information, but is now getting close votes *because it is a rock ID question*.

(The OT close reason says *Questions about rock identification requests are off-topic* and points to [Rock identification questions are now off topic. Old questions will be deleted. Should we retain any?](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/rock-identification-questions-are-now-off-topic-old-questions-will-be-deleted))

Is this what we want?

Comment: There is a sugestion to save paleontology id questions, but nobody commented anything and it had no upvotes. Apparently, when mods had time they are gonna delete and not only close fossils questions too (they say we could also do it with 3 votes of people with 2k, but they can do it quicker with their magic hammer). The message is uncorrect in that case I agree.

Answer (score 1):

I think we should keep it offtopic.

First of all, it is a rock. The fact that it is biogenic does not matter.

Second, a reason for making the rock-id questions off-topic is that they are unlikely to be useful to anyone other than the OP. This remains the case here with fossils.

Third, another reason for banning the rock-id questions was the negative traffic it brings to the site. It does not matter whether the people come here from a Google search of "help identify the rock" or "help identify this fossil". The outcome is the same.

The above said, if it's a good question with more value other than "I found this what is this", it should not be closed.

Comment: +1 especially for the last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think it should be kept. I have changed the title.

This site should support paleontology questions, as suggested in [Burninate `rocks` and `identification-request`? Promote `petrology` and `paleontology`?](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1775/burninate-rocks-and-identification-request-promote-petrology-and-paleont) (question not yet sufficiently voted on, commented on, or answered).