# Asking for help to +500 rep users to close id-request questions [Update: all are closed]

Tags: discussion

Ok, so to stop receiving those question, we should not appear firsts at Google common searches from users that want to know what is the stone they found. For that the 450 questions we have should be deleted, we cannot leave examples that Google will raster (even it is a good piece well pictured).

To delete a question it should be closed firstly.
The deletion task can only be done by +2k users, where I cannot help (it needs 3 votes and not 5 in this case).

I will send 25 questions each day to review since tomorrow to close. We are not asking for any criteria of closing, just it is an agreement to close and delete those questions, it takes 2 minutes/day and the task will be done in 10 days (around 200 are yet closed).

If you have +500 reputation, you will see a red point on the review icon advising there is task there. If you have two minutes to help thanks for it.

*I am not going for the moment to vote to close to fossils questions until it is clarified if the ban to id-my rock is extended to paleontology.*

---

## Every question is closed

*I couldn't vote to close in this question because I voted yet. Please, close it:

[I found this stone with metal linings can someone identify it?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/17459/i-found-this-stone-with-metal-linings-can-someone-identify-it)

Comment: Doing the same thing. For (paleontology) question that seem worth keeping, I edit them (usually the titles) to make them more on-topic.

Comment: @Jan Doggen I am also going to untag id-request the questions that are related with meteorology. Also, if you agree we can untag fossils questions too. Then the hole list of questions will be closed and prepared for deletion. I think it is congruent with the fact mods are gonna include the tag on some kind of black-list

Comment: Don't jump to conclusions. You are even stating as fact (in your edits) that the ID Request tag is going to be blacklisted, but that is nowhere to be found, especially not in https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1775/burninate-rocks-and-identification-request-promote-petrology-and-paleont

Comment: @Jan Doggen [here](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1758/ive-had-enough-lets-ban-rock-id-questions) on comments on Spencer answer "We can [ban the tag"], linking to a meta post of something called black list -> https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-blacklist/info

Comment: @Jan Doggen If you agree we can save fossils questions too for the moment, untag them too (just fossils and paleontology). That would leave the list with 100% of id-my-stone questions, all closed and prepared to be deleted without need of discrimination betweem questions.

Comment: @Universal_learner you do realise that we'll still appear high in Google for some time anyway?

In any case, I'm a +2k user, and I can't find the delete option...

Comment: @Semidiurnal Simon can you confirm you have the option on [closed question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14665/basalt-slag-or-meteorite)s please? Myself I like to order data, it gives me pleasure, but I guess the task is so boring we will wait for octobre to be gerrit who asume the time to delete the 400 questions. I ask it because, until octobre, it won't be a bad idea to delete questions that appear first for "identify my rock".You can type it yourself and see the five questions I am refering, but they are still on hold. System automatically put them closed in 5 days.

Comment: Today I typed "identify my rock" Semidiurnal and the first sugest of Google is no longer stack. It is usgs, that advices what we should have adviced since the first of those questions entered on our site ["Rocks and minerals are extremely difficult to identify through photographs. You will get the best results by taking your rock or mineral to a local source where it can be handled and examined closely"](https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/can-you-identify-my-rock-or-mineral?qt-news_science_products=0#qt-news_science_products)

Comment: I don't know what's the interaction between html of a closed question and Google's spider, but I think our acts are starting to have some effect.

Comment: Great!
Yes, I do see a (vote to) delete option on the linked closed question. I guess they have to be closed first before they can be deleted.