# Should we ask for the 3 votes to close-reopen feature?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

I have read [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364007/testing-three-vote-close-and-reopen-on-13-network-sites?cb=1) that say some sites are testing 3-votes to close and reopen feature.

In my opinion moderators should ask to include us in those sites. My reason is there are not enough reviewers in the site daily. For example [it was hard to me to movilize users](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1785/asking-for-help-to-500-rep-users-to-close-id-request-questions-update-all-are) to close and delete the [identify-my-rock](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-my-rock) questions.

It is even more clear 3 votes to reopen would be accurated. I have seen how many questions marked to reopen were never opened after an edit. For example we loosed some on-topic identify-my-fossil questions because the proposals to reopen them were not seconded by the reviewers (and they were deleted by inertia when we were deleting all questions with [identify-my-rock](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-my-rock) tag).

Answer (score 2):

No. There's not enough community members that want this.